# Create a new section while drag and drop cell in collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

Its is possible to create a new section while drag and drop the cell? I am able to rearrange cell into existing section but I am unable to create a new section. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but a little difficult.

You need to check the location in your tableview of your temporary cell *(the one you are moving)*

```
var center = TempCell.cellSnapshot!.center
center.y = locationInView.y
```

Then you have to check if the temporary cell is in an existing section with rows *(then you can just insert them like you are already doing)*:

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(locationInView)
```

or if `indexPath == nil` *(there must be an empty section)* you can loop through your headers *(assuming you have a header for your empty section)* and you get your closest header and you can create a new row in the empty section of this header.

Comment: Asking about collectionView with custom layout.